# Comparing two cards in the poker hand

Tags: java, class, exception

I'm trying to implement a poker hand class that has an array list of 5 cards and I need to check if there are any duplicate cards .. Here is the code but it gives me an error message saying that in the last if statement : the return type in missing ! I don't know what is that mean. it is an if statement. why do I need a return type ?!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Pokerhand {

   public final int CARDS_NUMBER = 5;
   private ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

   public Pokerhand(Card card1, Card card2, Card card3, Card card4, Card card5) {
      cards.add(card1);
      cards.add(card2);
      cards.add(card3);
      cards.add(card4);
      cards.add(card5);
   }

   private boolean checkCorrectness(ArrayList<Card> cards) {
      if (cards.size() != CARDS_NUMBER)
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect number of cards!! ");

      for (int i = 0; i < cards.size() - 1; i++) {
         for (int j = i + 1; j < cards.size(); j++) {
            if (cards.get(j).equals(cards.get(j + 1)))
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicat card");

         }
      }

      return true;
   }

   if (checkCorrectness (cards)) 
      this.cards = cards;
}
```

Comment: Because otherwise you aren't returning anything, and you say the method returns a boolean.

Comment: @Andreas Yes .. this is my actual code..

Comment: @Andreas .. The last if statement is red-highlighted and the error message says :Return type for the method is missing

Comment: Got it. You have your braces messed up.

Answer (score 2):

Please, you need to fix a bunch of style problems first, even before your logic can be assessed. Once that is done, the problems with the logic should become obvious:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Represents a hand of cards in a game of Poker.
 */
public class Pokerhand {

    /**
     * The number of cards in a valid poker hand. Hands with other numbers of
     * cards are not considered valid.
     */
    public final int HAND_SIZE = 5;

    private Card [] cards;

    /**
     * Constructs a new hand containing the given cards.
     * @param cards The cards this hand is to contain.
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException if the cards passed do not form a valid
     *     hand.  A hand is considered valid if there are exactly
     *     {@code HAND_SIZE} cards, and no repeated cards.
     * @see Pokerhand#isValidHand
     */
    public Pokerhand(Card ... cards) throws InvalidArgumentException {
        if(isValidHand(cards)) 
            this.cards = cards;
        else
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Bad hand");
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the cards passed together form a valid hand. A hand is
     * considered valid if there are exactly {@code HAND_SIZE} cards, and no
     * repeated cards.
     * @param cards The cards to check
     * @return {@code true} if the cards form a valid hand,
     *         {@code false} otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isValidHand(Card ... cards){
        if (cards.length != HAND_SIZE)
            return false;

        for(int i=0; i < cards.size()-1; i++)
            for(int j=i+1; j < cards.size(); j++)
                if(cards[j].equals(cards[j+1]))
                    return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Reasoning for changes:

- Everything should have a javadoc.
- `checkCorectness` is a really bad name for that method. A `boolean` method should be named so that the status represented by its return value is immediately obvious. As a more extreme example, what would you expect `checkIfNotX(x)` to return? The method should be named what it returns, not what it does. `isValidHand` is a far better name.
- `isValidHand` should be `public` because users of the class may wish to follow the "check first" pattern rather than the "ask for forgiveness" pattern.
- `isValidHand` should not be throwing exceptions, for the exact same reason it should be `public`.
- `cards` should be an array, because nothing you are doing with them requires any of the dynamic capabilities of a `List`.
- `isValidHand` and `Pokerhand` should take varargs, because that way is much more transparent, and it makes them much easier to use.

Now, as you can see, the error is in the `if` statement inside the nested `for` loops in `isValidHand`. Your compiler should be giving you a warning, saying that `i` is never used. The condition should read `cards[i].equals(cards[j])`.

Answer (score 1):

You have your braces messed up: The last two statements look like they are within the `class` scope, but you can not have an `if` statement at the class scope:

```
    }  // end checkCorrectness(...)

    if (checkCorrectness (cards)) 
        this.cards = cards;
} // end class
```

Important rule: always properly format your code, including reasonable indents - that makes it easier to spot such issues.

You probably meant to check the correctness of the cards, after they have been added in your constructor - then, remove the two lines mentioned above and do something like this instead:

```
public Pokerhand(Card card1, Card card2, Card card3, Card card4, Card card5) {
  cards.add(card1);
  cards.add(card2);
  cards.add(card3);
  cards.add(card4);
  cards.add(card5);

  checkCorrectness (cards);  // throws exception if the card definition is wrong
}
```

That should solve your immediate issue with the code you showed in the question. See @AJMansfield's answer on how to improve your `Pokerhand` API - too many parameters in a constructor are usually a hint of bad API design.

Comment: Why ?! then what to do if I want to call the method to check the correctness of the cards ?!

Comment: You can only call a method from within another method. There's a special method in Java, `public static void main(String[] args)` that is invoked when a program is run. All other methods are invoked from other methods including, possibly, `main`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to handle the exception at the function, you should explicitly mark the function as `throws IllegalArgumentException`

Example:

```
private boolean checkCorrectness(ArrayList<Card> cards) throws IllegalArgumentException
```

Otherwise, you should consider switching the `return-type` to something that can give you more information like `int` or `enum`(preferable) and returning the error code.

If we choose `int` than consider this:

```
-1 = "Incorrect number of cards"
-2 = "Duplicate card"
```

Example:

```
private int checkCorrectness(ArrayList<Card> cards)
```

Comment: I still can't understand what's wrong with this boolean return type ?!

Comment: @EmanHamed because exceptions are supposed to be _exceptional_, not a standard occurrence.